# Is there a way to fallback to built in formatter?

Tags: tabulator

I have [tabulator](http://tabulator.info) column like this:

```
    {
      title: "P", width: 50,
      editor     : 'tickCross',
      formatter  : function( cell, params ) {
        if( x ) {
          return 'my own format';
        }

        return fall_back_to_tickCross();
      }
    },
```

As you can see I want to render my own value for some rows.
But when condition does not meet then I want to fallback to some of built in formatter ('tickCross' in this case)

Is there a way to fallback to built in formatter?

Comment: The only I can think of is to build a custom formatter:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format#format-custom
and then incorporate the tickCross code from here:
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/format.js
line 308 or so.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Nice hint. Thank you. I will investigate